# Adding manager attribute fails

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that matches a contact based on an email in a csv, I can find the contact using a get-adobject -ldapfilter but when I try to add the contact as a manager the add fails stating it cannot find the contact.  The contact it states it cannot find is clearly present in the directory.

This line will find the contact:

```
$rmanager = Get-ADObject -SearchBase 'OU=workplace,OU=Contacts,DC=office,DC=com' -ldapfilter "(&(objectclass=contact)(name=$fname*)(name=*$lname))"
```

---

An example of the contact in question being found...

```
PS C:\temp> Get-ADObject -SearchBase 'OU=workplace,OU=Contacts,DC=office,DC=com' -ldapfilter "(&(objectclass=contact)(name=$fname*)(name=*$lname))"

DistinguishedName Name ObjectClass ObjectGUID 
----------------- ---- ----------- ---------- 
CN=Nick Hill,OU=workplace,OU=Contacts,DC=office,DC=com Nick Hill contact b649bd7e-aac9-4d4b-8203-b6a79f35b91
```

However, this line with the set-aduser will fail stating it cannot find the contact that clearly exists...

```
get-aduser -f {mail -eq $username} |set-aduser -Manager "$rmanager"



set-aduser : Identity info provided in the extended attribute: 'Manager' could not be resolved. Reason: 'Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=Nick Hill,OU=Workplace,OU=Contacts,DC=office,DC=com' under: 'DC=Office,DC=com'.'.
```

Comment: A user object is not a contact object.

Comment: Bill, this is the same question, just asked differently as I didn't get an answer to the other one.

Comment: I did actually answer your question in a comment on your other question.

Comment: Bill, I was under the impression that the manager attrib only stored a DN, could this DN not be the DN of a contact?

Comment: Yes, you can make a contact the manager of a user object, but not using `Set-ADUser`. It looks like you can use `Set-ADObject`, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and it worked:

a. Get distinguishedName of contact:

```
$contactDN = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(objectClass=contact)(givenName=firstname)(sn=lastname))"
  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

b. Get the user object and replace the `manager` attribute:

```
Get-ADUser username | Get-ADObject | Set-ADObject -Replace @{"manager" = $contactDN}
```

Comment: Thank you Bill, I was missing the get-adobject part, this works for me as well!